# How to display image height and width in pixels?

Tags: 7, views, media

I have image size, but I can't find any field for image height and with in Views.

I need to display orginal image height and weight, something like: Resolution: 800px x 600px.

Comment: I think you're going to need the [File entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module for that. Then add a relationship from the image field to the file entity, and you should be able to extract the image dimensions. Per [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1365206), though, there's no support for filters currently. You could of course just do it in a preprocess function though if that's too much overhead

Comment: I suspect people are struggling to answer the question because it's not very clear. If you want to display height and width values along with an image then probably the easiest way is to use a custom theme function. Are you OK with writing PHP?

Comment: Also see this small module, which may be what you want: https://www.drupal.org/project/image_wh_formatter

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an image style for the image (what used to be ImageCache in Drupal 6 now in Core)?  Configuration -> Media -> Image Styles

If not perhaps you should because this will give you much more control over the size of an image without having to worry about theming the size directly.  Set up a preset for the image display in question and you can choose the size it should be generated at for a particular use.

Comment: I need to display orginal image height and weight, something like: Resolution: 800px x 600px

Comment: Do you have already check https://www.drupal.org/project/exif and https://www.drupal.org/project/exif_custom  ?